# TCP Server using perl fork to accept multiple requests

Tags: perl

I'm trying to create a little server who handles multiple clients connections (at least 10). Below the current code that works perfect using fork. At least it accepts several connections from clients.

With the below code, I have the following behaviour:

- Client ask for connection ==> Accepted ==> OK
- Client sent packet ==> Received and printed ==> OK
- Client sent another packet ==> Not received ==> NOK

Most probably, the while cicle will be activated only for each connection request, so that's the reason because I cannot retrieve other packets.

Could someone help me please to adjust the below code? What I need is establish one (or more) client connection, then client send data continuosly (without disconnection) and server should reply on each packet it receives.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use IO::Socket::INET;

$SIG{CHLD} = sub {wait ()};
my $socket = new IO::Socket::INET (
    LocalHost => '0.0.0.0',
    LocalPort => '5000',
    Proto => 'tcp',
    Listen => 5,
    Reuse => 1);
die "cannot create socket $!n" unless $socket;

while ($new_sock = $socket->accept()) {
   $pid = fork();
   die "Cannot fork: $!" unless defined($pid);

   if ($pid == 0) {     # This is the fork child
      $new_sock->recv(my $data, 500);
      print "$data\n";
   }
}
```

Comment: I'd recommend some reading, and there are full examples (and discussion) in [perlipc](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlipc). Also, there are full examples for server and client out on internet.  (Searching with "_perl TCP server_" brings up the whole first page of examples, and probably way more later)

Comment: I'm grateful of all contributors. But I don't understand comments with "search solution on Google". I already spent hours on code (and on google :) ) before posting here, and evidently I have not found anything that can suite to my needs! ;) Anyway, thank you for your reply.

Comment: Lincoln Stein's *Network Programming in Perl* is an old book, but not as old as TCP. It should have everything you need, and it's easy to find online.

Comment: @LucasRey "_But I don't understand comments with "search solution on Google"_" -- Sorry you didn't like that, it wasn't meant to slight you in any sense.  It's just that the first page of hits to the phrase I quoted is full of complete examples of TCP server/client. Full code with everything.  Why reproduce that here?  That's why I made a comment.  I don't know that you searched, since you are asking and solutions are plentiful out there.  I do appreciate your good effort.

Comment: @LucasRey (And I didn't say "_Search solution on Google_" -- I stated that there were full examples on the first page reached by a specific search term.  Not the same.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to loop around the `recv` call to read more than one package from the client. Also, as it's currently written, the `SIGCHLD` signal interrupts `accept` so when the first child process dies, your server program terminates. You could just add a loop around the `accept` loop to restart the `accept` call.

Example:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use IO::Socket::INET;

$SIG{CHLD} = sub { wait; };

my $socket = new IO::Socket::INET (
    LocalHost => '0.0.0.0',
    LocalPort => '5000',
    Proto => 'tcp',
    Listen => 5,
    Reuse => 1);
die "cannot create socket $!n" unless $socket;

sub child {
    my $sock = shift;
    my $data;
    print "$$ connected\n";
    # loop for as long as there's something coming in
    while($sock->recv($data, 500) || $data) {
        print "$$ $data";  # prepend the data with the process id
    }
    print "$$ disconnected\n";
    exit 0;
}

while(1) {
    while (my $new_sock = $socket->accept()) {
        my $pid = fork();
        die "Cannot fork: $!" unless defined($pid);

        if ($pid == 0) {     # This is the fork child
            child($new_sock);
        }
    }
    print "accept interrupted - restarting\n";
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Ted Lyngmo but it seems I'm not able to receive data at all using the above example

Comment: @LucasRey That's odd since I used your code as a base. Does the `accept` call succeed? Does the `child` die directly on the first `recv`? I updated it to print `connected` and `disconnected` too. Do you get those? Do you use the same program to send data as you did when testing your own server program?

Comment: sorry for late response, I was busy. Now is working, thank you for your time!